# GNU make: suffix rule combined with custom rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have the following:

```
myfile.xyz: myfile.abc
        mycommand

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .xyz .abc

.abc.xyz:
        flip -e abc "$<" > "logs/$*.log"
```

Now suppose I want to have `mycommand` be a custom rule (as it is currently) but *also* have the suffix rule run afterward (or before). That is, I do not want my custom rule to replace the suffix rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible in gnu make. There are double colon rules which allows multiple recipes for one target, but they do not work with suffix rules or pattern rules. See [the make manual about double colon rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon) for more information.

Here is a workaround:

```
.SUFFIXES:           # Delete the default suffixes
.SUFFIXES: .xyz .abc # Define our suffix list

.abc.xyz: 
        flip -e abc "$<" > "logs/$*.log"
        if [ myfile.abc = "$<" ]; then mycommand; fi
```

And here is the same makefile using pattern rules instead of suffix rules:

```
%.xyz: %.abc
        flip -e abc "$<" > "logs/$*.log"
        if [ myfile.abc = "$<" ]; then mycommand; fi
```

See the [make manual about pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) and [old-fashioned suffix rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules) for more information.